# Countdown for SAPUI5 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

i'm new in SAPUI5 and hoping anyone can help me with my question.

I want to create an Countdown in an ObjectStatus XML - element.

```
<ObjectStatus id="myTime" title="Time runs of in" text="{timeFromModel}"    state="Success" />
```

I have no idea how to begin. In jQuery i would do it this way:

```
setInterval( function(){
  var currentTime = new Date();

  // Get time from oModel, calculate the time difference

   $('myTime').val(newDifference);

}, 10000);
```

Comment: Inspect the target element to be selected using jQuery selector...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setText](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ObjectStatus.html#setText) of [sap.m.ObjectStatus](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ObjectStatus.html) control to set the value dynamically.

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/comacac/4/edit?html,js,output)